# Defining Spring DataSource programmatically gets me ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have this DataSource bean below which creates a datasource using my Hibernate properties.

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

I have the spring-jdbc jar depency set up in Maven. I also have the relevant classes imported with no compile errors.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When I initialize my application, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`. Would anyone know why my application would be unable to find this class?

Comment: Check you WEB-INF/lib folder, does your war contains this jar in it?

Comment: then do you see the jar in your Deployment Assembly?

Comment: @dhamibirendra This is what my Deployment Assembly looks like: http://i.imgur.com/M6jyoTS.png

Comment: I've also confirmed that spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar is in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: then this could be some synchronization issue.. Remove the war from tomcat, then clean tomcat and refresh your project and redeploy

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my issue by changing the Maven dependency to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

There was probably some dependency issue with my other jars.